# Postgres ORDER BY value inside json causes "column does not exist" error

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is a strange error. I have the following query that returns the data I want:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(block.name, 'Other') as name,
    json_agg(set.data) as sets
FROM
    set
    FULL OUTER JOIN block ON set.block_id = block.id
GROUP BY block.id
```

[image]

Note that "sets" is a json column with perfectly valid data. Now all I want to do is sort the output by a value the "sets" column, so I add the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(block.name, 'Other') as name,
    json_agg(set.data) as sets
FROM
    set
    FULL OUTER JOIN block ON set.block_id = block.id
GROUP BY block.id
ORDER BY sets->0->>'releaseDate'
```

And it somehow tells me that "sets" doesn't exist:

[image]

Why on earth is this happening and how can I get this to work?

*edit if it helps, here's a pastebin you can use to construct the same schema that I  have: http://pastebin.com/UZa0jZXi*

---

This may not be relevant, but  if I don't use any json operators at all, and try to just sort by "sets" (not that that will work), Postgres at least acknowledges that the column exists:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(block.name, 'Other') as name,
    json_agg(set.data) as sets
FROM
    set
    FULL OUTER JOIN block ON set.block_id = block.id
GROUP BY block.id
ORDER BY sets
```

[image]

Comment: You can probably fix this using a CTE or subquery, without understanding why this isn't working.

Comment: That's true, I can wrap it in a subquery and sort the outer query by inner.sets->0->>'releaseDate', but that makes no sense!

Comment: *(This was a reply to a deleted comment)* There's no WHERE clause in this query. The error is in the ORDER BY clause which is executed after the SELECT.

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: 9.4.4, the newest stable version

Comment: If anyone wants to play with the data, here's a pastebin that builds the same schema that I have: http://pastebin.com/UZa0jZXi

Comment: This indeed seems to be a Postgres bug. The error message is very misleading at least. I would consider [using this form](http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug/).

Comment: @klin It's not a bug, it's the way it always worked and the behaviour is described in the manual (see the close vote).

Comment: You are correct. That's very strange behaviour however. Is a subquery really the only workaround?

Comment: Thanks @Jakub. There is no bug of course. I read the paragraph at least three times today... On Christmas thoughts turn strange paths.

Comment: @Miguel That is not strange behaviour at all, aliases in ORDER BY cause a lot of problems. Use `ORDER BY json_agg(set.data)->0->>'releaseDate'` or wrap it in a query.

Comment: Alright, I think that's the answer I'm looking for. Thanks!